# Using the Row_Number function

Tags: sql, window-functions

My data looks like this -

```
clientid    calendar    Num
18161       20170518    1
18161       20170705    0
18161       20170718    0
43431       20150518    0
```

The first 0 `Num` for `18161` client is on the 2nd calendar. The first 0 `Num` for `43431` client is on the 1st calendar (`20150518`). I want a SQL to generate this output -

```
clientid    FirstZero
18161       2 
43431       1
```

This is what I have so far, but the row_number is being generated for all `calendars`. I need it just for the first time `Num` becomes zero for a particular client.

```
SELECT clientid, calendar,
Row_Number() Over (order by clientid) As FirstZero
from DAILY
where num = 0  
and clientid = 18161
```

Comment: And? That is what you have so far, and what is wrong with it?

Comment: @dfundako I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
select
  clientid,
  min(pos) as firstzero
from (
  select
    clientid,
    num,
    row_number() over(partition by clientid order by calendar) as pos
  from daily
) x
where num = 0
group by clientid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with fz as 
(
SELECT clientid, calendar, num, 
Row_Number() Over (partition by clientId order by calendar) As FirstZero
from DAILY
),
gz as
(
  select clientid, min(FirstZero) as FirstZero 
  from fz
  where num = 0
  group by clientId
)
select d.clientId, d.calendar, gz.firstZero
 from Daily d 
 inner join fz on d.clientId = fz.clientId and d.calendar = fz.calendar
 inner join gz on fz.clientId = gz.clientId and fz.firstZero = gz.firstZero
 --where d.clientId = 18161
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fb16bb0d2cf0caf8655d9d96d514fd91)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE to make your row_numbers, and then find the MIN()

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT clientID, 
Calendar, 
Num, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY clientid ORDER BY calendar) AS counter_
FROM table
)
SELECT 
clientID, MIN(counter_) AS FirstZero
FROM cte 
WHERE Num=0
GROUP BY clientID
```

Comment: What's that semicolon right at the beginning? (I've seen several posts with it)

Comment: @TheImpaler Standard SQL Server syntax for a CTE so it doesn't throw a "previous statement must be terminated with semicolon" error